# How to setup/configure git to ignore a folder just locally

Tags: git

In our enterprise project, we maintain our code base in 3 branches in GIT namely, Release_1, Release_2 and Release_3.

The GIT repository is huge and multiple teams use it. The remote desktop provided to us has limited hard drive capacity. So I am trying to reduce the size of my GIT. In that pursuit, I found a folder which is not relevant to me or my team. Say folder ABC. I want to ignore this folder completely. But just for me.

Is there anyway to forget folder ABC locally or any other way to reduce the size of GIT repo?

Options tried till now:

1. .gitignore -> This will make the folder be ignored for other teams as well. If I keep it locally, may be accidently I might push to server and make it ignored for everyone. So not taking this option for now.
2. .git/info/exlude -> Added folder ABC in this file, but upon switching from Release_x to Release_y, the complete folder ABC is again downloaded.

Comment: Did you try a [Partial Clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone)?

Comment: That would require me to do a git clone again, right? I shall keep that as last option as it would hamper my current work stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution:**

1. Create a new file in .git/info/ named "sparse-checkout"
2. In the newly created file add just the folders you need as follows:

Folder_1/

Folder_2/

3. Open new git bash and run the following commands:

git config core.sparsecheckout true
git read-tree -mu HEAD